# Count occurences in pandas column database and bar plot with matplotlib

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

So I have a pandas database with 4 columns.

Date A B C.

The dates contain all daily dates from year 2018, 2019 and 2020.

These columns A B C contains numbers from 1 to 7. No decimals.
I want to count each of this number occurences and stack them into a bar plot.
Count all 1's, 2's, 3's ect.

Anyone got a good solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Using `melt` with `value_counts`

```
df.melt('Date').value.value_counts().plot(kind='bar')
```